# CSS media queries doesn't reflect the device screen size

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm building a mobile web app and I created this media query to target phones with a lower screen height than the iPhone X+ (812px) :

```
@media (max-height: 811px) {

}
```

It works perfectly on iOS devices but when I launch the app on a Huawei P30 pro, which clearly have a bigger screen than the iPhone, it enter in the above media query and the viewport height seems to be only 755px.

Why did the Huawei, with a bigger screen, have a smaller viewport height ?

What can I do to target only phones that have a physically smaller screen than the iPhone X ?

Comment: What is the `window.screen.height` of both devices? Do you have a status bar at the top of the app? Is it the same on both devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make this change in your **index.html** - This is the one I would say is likely to be the issue for you

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

---

Or you could try this change in your **CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-device-height: 811px) {

}
```